# Category of QEMU

Tags: virtualbox, qemu

There are two kinds of VMM(Virtual Machine Monitor) accord to their virtualization level, *system VM* and *process VM*.
I know that KVM is a "**system VM**", and what about QEMU?
Is it same as KVM?

Comment: QEMU (short for Quick Emulator) is a free and open-source hosted hypervisor that performs hardware virtualization (not to be confused with hardware-assisted virtualization). QEMU needs KVM’s performance boost. However, it is clear that KVM by itself cannot provide the complete virtualization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QEMU can actually fonction in either mode, providing [full system emulation](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/qemu-doc.html#QEMU-PC-System-emulator) (and running a complete operating system) or only [CPU emulation for a single process](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/qemu-doc.html#QEMU-User-space-emulator).

QEMU can also function with or without KVM; if KVM is available, QEMU can use it as an accelerator.

Comment: So it will play a role as **process system VM** when executing program by QEMU on the command line? Since it emulate only for a single process?

Comment: No, it's either/or; if you start `qemu-system-...` then it's a full VM (or system VM), if you start `qemu-...` (*e.g.* `qemu-i386`) then it's a process VM.

Comment: Thanks.
Is there any difference between "qemu-system-i386" and "qemu-i386"?
Since the former is so-called system VM and the latter is process VM just because of the key word "**system**"?

Comment: `qemu-system-i386` starts an i386-based system emulator (or VM), with all the usual peripherals; it expects to boot a full operating system. `qemu-i386` runs the given binary by translating it, it only emulates an i386 CPU without any peripherals and expects to be able to run the given binary on the current operating system.

Answer (score 0):

KVM is built on to of QEMU and QEMU is a system VM as you are calling it.

I do not know your source of information, but from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine

> A system virtual machine provides a complete system platform which supports the execution of a complete operating system (OS).

and http://qemu.weilnetz.de/qemu-doc.html#intro_005ffeatures

> Full system emulation. In this mode, QEMU emulates a full system (for example a PC), including one or several processors and various peripherals. It can be used to launch different Operating Systems without rebooting the PC or to debug system code.